Manhwa where female MC's soul revives in the body of someone else
I am looking for a manhwa where the female MC died and got reincarnated in the same universe in the body of a different person, a princess I think. After being reincarnated she is married to the same person she was married to in her previous life, a husband who cannot get over the death of said previous life. However, the reincarnated MC can't seem to talk about her being reincarnated because of some restriction. The manga is fully coloured and I believe pre reincarnation female MC had purple hair and post reincarnation some shade of pink hair

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When did you read this? Did you read this online? Can you recall if the art style was in-colour or if it was black-and-white?

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Do you remember anything about the female lead's life before she died?
